# Should the DNS and web server be on the same location?

Tags: domain-name-system

I own 2 domain names pointing to the same webserver:

- the DNS server of domainA.com is hosted by provider **A** (e.g. in New-York)
- the DNS server of domainB.com is hosted by provider **B** (e.g. in London)
- the web server is hosted by provider **B** (e.g. in London)

Does the distance between provider A and provider B affect the DNS resolution time?

In other words, if I live in Paris, is it faster to access the server with domainA.com or domainB.com? Or are is it equivalent?

Comment: Why not just outsource DNS to one of the many hosts that have anycast DNS, like [Amazon Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/)?

Answer (score 1):

Best Practices (and RFCs) dictate that you should have redundant DNS servers. So if you manage two servers (which it sounds like you do), I would recommend configuring both servers to handle DNS for both domains.

You should configure 1 as your "Master" DNS server, and 1 as a "Slave" DNS server (i.e. the slave replicates whatever changes you make on the Master). This has the added advantage of only having to make changes to the master.

Assuming you configure DNS correctly, you don't really get to decide which DNS server is used for a particular website. It's good to have the DNS servers geographically dispersed, so that if something happens like a natural disaster in an area, your domains still resolve.

It's much better for a domain to resolve (but still be down due to the actual web server being down) than it is for everything to be down (domain doesn't resolve at all).

The title of your question asks should DNS and Web Server be in the same location. The answer I would give is that if you only manage two servers, then yes - you need to run DNS on two different servers, and it's perfectly fine to run BIND or another DNS service on the same server that is hosting the website.

Just make sure you have a redundant DNS server somewhere else.

In terms of speed, generally the DNS server that is closer to you will respond more quickly than 1 that is further away, but there are many factors and variables that go into how DNS works and how DNS servers respond... and as mentioned several times already, you need to run at least two DNS servers.